# How to append incremental build number to maven release?

Tags: maven, jenkins, versioning

I've recently been implementing a CI system for work. The way I understand maven versions is that it can be of the form `x.x.x-y-z`. We want to have nightly builds in our CI system and have it tagged as `x.x.x-y` where `y` would go up on every nightly build. The next development version would stay as `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT`. This way our version numbers don't go up like crazy, only the build number does. And we can pick a particular tag and promote it to testing/UAT/production etc.

However, when I try to do a release with the maven release plugin on `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT` it increments the next version to `x.x.x+1-SNAPSHOT`. Or I can have `x.x.x-y-SNAPSHOT` which is quite ugly.

Currently we have a python build script that we use to achieve this, but it is hard to maintain. We want to try to move to a more standardized system that allows us to have nightly builds without having version numbers go up like crazy and still be able to track which version of the code is running on which server.

Is there a way of setting up maven/Jenkins to do what I have described? Is there a better more standardized way to achieve similar functionality?

As a messy solution I am thinking of taking the relevant chunks out of the python script and running them with Jenkins. However, I know there has to be a more elegant way of doing this.

Edit: I'm using maven 3.2.1

Comment: Did you try to use [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) ?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @Vitalii I Tried the maven release plugin, it makes the next development version go to x.x.x-y+1-SNAPSHOT which is undesirable.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using maven 3.2

Comment: 3.2 what? 3.2.1 or 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.5 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise version 3.2.1 to be precise.

Comment: You can use properties take a look into release notes http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html you can use things like `${revision}`, `${changelist}`, and `${sha1}`.